# Does ColdFusion support delegates?

Tags: coldfusion, delegates, dry, coldfusion-9

I have several database access methods that are wrapped in a try/catch block:

```
function GetAll() {
    try {
        entityLoad("Book");
    }
    catch (any e) {
        throw (type="CustomException", message="Error accessing database, could not read");
    }
}

function Save(Book book) {
    try {
        entitySave(book);
    }
    catch (any e) {
        throw (type="CustomException", message="Error accessing database, could not save);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the try/catch block is repeated several times, where the only thing that varies is the message. Is it possible to create a delegate in ColdFusion so that I can do something like this instead (using a C# lambda to represent an anonymous delegate)?:

```
function GetAll() {
    DatabaseOperation(() => entityLoad("Book"), "could not read");
}

function Save(Book book) {
    DatabaseOperation(() => entitySave(book), "could not save");
}

function DatabaseOperation(delegate action, string error) {
    try {
        action.invoke();
    }
    catch (any e) {
        var message = "Error accessing database, " & error;
        throw (type="CustomException", message=message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your example, not with CF9.

Closures are coming in CF10 which will probably allow you to do something like:

```
function GetAll() {
    DatabaseOperation( closure(){ entityLoad("Book") } , "could not read");
}

function Save(Book book) {
    DatabaseOperation( closure(){ entitySave(book) } , "could not save");
}

function DatabaseOperation(closure action, string error) {
    try {
        action();
    }
    catch (any e) {
        var message = "Error accessing database, " & error;
        throw (type="CustomException", message=message);
    }
}
```

(syntax might vary, don't remember if it was exactly like that)

Alternatively, you could probably use `evaluate` here, I guess...

```
function GetAll() {
    DatabaseOperation( 'entityLoad("Book")' , "could not read");
}

function Save(Book book) {
    DatabaseOperation( 'entitySave(book)' , "could not save");
}

function DatabaseOperation(string action, string error) {
    try {
        evaluate(action);
    }
    catch (any e) {
        var message = "Error accessing database, " & error;
        throw (type="CustomException", message=message);
    }
}
```

Personally I would just remove the try/catch and use `onError` in `Application.cfc` - doesn't seem to be useful to mask the original error and instead throw a more generic one?

**Update: two more possible alternatives...**

Another option that currently works is to have a public wrapper function, that calls the DatabaseOperation function, passing in the name of a private function that does the actual logic like this:

```
function GetAll() {
    DatabaseOperation( real_GetAll , Arguments , "could not read");
}
private function real_GetAll() {
    entityLoad("Book")
}

function Save(Book book) {
    DatabaseOperation( real_Save , Arguments , "could not save");
}
private function real_Save(Book book) {
    entitySave(book)
}

function DatabaseOperation(any action, struct args , string error) {
    try {
        action( argumentcollection=args )
    }
    catch (any e) {
        var message = "Error accessing database, " & error;
        throw (type="CustomException", message=message);
    }
}
```

If you don't like the idea of defining functions twice, but don't mind obscuring the API, you could set the methods to private then use onMissingMethod:

```
private function GetAll()
{
    entityLoad("Book")
}

private function Save(Book book)
{
    entitySave(book)
}

function onMissingMethod( string MethodName , struct MethodArgs )
{
    if ( NOT StructKeyExists(Variables,Arguments.MethodName) )
    {
        throw("The method #Arguments.MethodName# was not found");
    }

    try
    {
        var Meth = Variables[Arguments.MethodName];
        Meth( ArgumentCollection=Arguments.MethodArgs );
    }
    catch(any e)
    {
        var message = "Error accessing database, ";

        switch(MethodName)
        {
            case "GetAll":
                message &= "could not read";
            break;
            case "Save":
                message &= "could not save";
            break;
        }

        throw (type="CustomException,message=message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. The example I gave was just a generic one. In the actual application, we're wrapping a bunch of vague exceptions thrown by the framework with some custom ones that make more sense to developers.

Comment: To be clear, this is not a case of whether or not you can create delegates in ColdFusion, right? This is really about supporting anonymous functions. Which, as Peter said, will be coming in the next version.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably something worth clarifying - I've seen `delegates` term every so often, but still not entirely sure what they are, (and wikipedia page doesn't really make it clearer), but if it's just about passing functions around and executing them, that's already possible - it's only the anonymous functions aspect that isn't there yet.

Comment: Yes, anonymous functions would be what I'm aiming for. As far as I understand it (which is probably wrong), delegates are simply wrappers around functions that allows you to pass them around like variables.